# When to use "GOP" versus "Republican Party"

Tags: word-choice

I've read lots of professional articles that use the two terms interchangeably, sometimes within the same paragraph. Are the two terms really semantically identical? In formal writing, are there any situations where it would be recommended to use one or the other?

Comment: It should be noted that some US states have their own terms for the parties.  In Minnesota, for example, the Republicans are "IR", for "Independent Republicans", while the Democrats are "DFL", for "Democrat/Farmer/Labor".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In more formal writing, it's slightly more proper to use the phrase "Republican Party". However, in general discussion or news reporting, you'll find it used interchangeably.

GOP (Grand Old Party) is a nickname for the [Republican Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_Party_(United_States)) that dates back over a century. The use of the word 'old' is ironic in that the [Democratic Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)) was founded before the Republican Party. Also, some of the alternate meanings of the word '[grand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grand)' cause members of opposing parties to use the term GOP sarcastically, or not at all.

It is favored in news headlines due to its shortness.

Comment: It should be mentioned that some candidates (such as Dino Rossi in Washington State) ran as a "GOP" candidate vs. "Republican Party". It may be that the terms are truly becoming interchangeable. http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/localnews/2008199160_rossisuit24m.html

Comment: I thought that _GOP_ would mean _Govern of People_; at least that is was said from a person living in the East coast of the USA.

Comment: Worth noting: 'Dems' for Democrats is fine, but 'Reps' for Republicans would cause confusion due to the word 'Representatives' being abbreviated to 'Reps'. Thus, GOP is a much clearer abbreviation for Republicans.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Said person was wrong. Perhaps they'd *like* it to mean that...

Comment: As a Brit, I would suggest using "Republican Party" if any of your intended readership comes from across the pond. "GOP" is a relatively recent introduction to the UK (I assume due to the influence of US media and possibly that it saves characters in headlines) and is still less often used over here.

Comment: [GOP](https://trademarks.justia.com/746/08/gop-74608550.html) has been a registered trademark of the Republican National Committee since 1994

Comment: @jsw29 Typo. I meant 'slightly more proper'.

Comment: It is probably no coincidence that "Grand Old Party" came into use at a time when the victorious Union army of the U.S. Civil War was widely referred to as "the Grand Army of the Republic." An influential organization of Union veterans also used this name, and the [Wikipedia article about the veterans group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Army_of_the_Republic) notes that "The GAR initially grew and prospered as a de facto political arm of the Republican Party during the heated political contests of the Reconstruction Era." ...

Comment: ... The association of the Republican Party with the North and of the Democratic Party with the South was very strong in the late 1800s, although Democrats made considerably more headway in the North (to the extent of electing a northern Democrat president in 1884 and 1892 and almost electing another one in 1876) than the Republicans did in the South once southern Whites who had fought for the Confederacy regained the right to vote and repression of (largely Republican) Black voters commenced in earnest.

Answer (score 6):

"GOP" stands for Grand Old Party ([dating from 1876](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=GOP&searchmode=none)), and is used as a somewhat informal synonym meaning the Republican Party. Its usage is mainly in the press, as its size makes it ideal for headlines and news copy. Example headline:

> **GOP blasts Dems on spending**

If you were writing a formal paper on politics, you might prefer to say "the Republican Party" or "the Republicans" or just "Republicans" — but there is nothing preventing you from salting in references to "the GOP" as well.

About the only places you aren't likely to see it at all are on formal invitations or legal documents.

Comment: It is noteworthy that, even though *GOP* is an abbreviation of a phrase that includes *grand*, a term that normally expresses a favourable, respectful attitude to what it refers to, the use of that abbreviation in discussions of the current US politics carries no such suggestions: it can be found in the contexts that are critical of Republican policies as well as those that support them.

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_Party_%28United_States%29):

> The term "Grand Old Party" is a traditional nickname for the Republican Party, and the initialism "G.O.P." (or "GOP") is a commonly used designation

, and refers to the OED:

> The first reference to the Republican Party as the "grand old party" is dated to 1876; the first use of the abbreviation "GOP" is dated 1884.

Both terms are fairly interchangeable, and while GOP is mainly used in headlines, it is interesting to know that, as detailed in the article "[What Does 'GOP' Stand For?](http://www.cbsnews.com/stories/2002/12/03/politics/main531460.shtml)", in 2002 The Wall Street Journal actually had decided to stop(!) using the acronym to refer to the 148-year-old political party.

> In an internal memo issued to staffers last week, Journal higher-ups said the term GOP will be dropped because not all readers know what the letters mean, and some may not realize that they are a reference to the Republican Party.

Titles like "[Democrats Aim to Curb GOP Donors](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704518104575546450619007906.html)" (on the online Wall Street Journal site) show that this resolution didn't stick.

Comment: Interesting info about the WSJ's official and de-facto stances.

Comment: The problem for headline writers is that, whereas "Dem" and "Dems" is instantly and unambiguously recognizable as a short form for "Democrat[ic Party]" and "Democrats," no such clarity attends "Rep" and "Reps," which are likely (depending on context) to be read as short forms for "Representative" and "Representatives" rather than for "Republican [Party]" and "Republicans." The utilitarian value of "GOP" in the limited space of a headline is, as Robusto's answer suggests, by no means trivial.

Answer (score 3):

When writing for an international audience, use Republican Party.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

GOP is an acronym standing for Grand Old Party, a nickname for The Republican Party, and as far as I know is synonymous.

Disclaimer: I am not American.

Answer (score -1):

Using GOP instead of Republican Party is an absolute waste of marketing opportunity to recruit new Republicans to the party. Most uniformed people have no idea what it stands for and causes confusion.  No experienced marketing strategist would recommend using this nickname as a sound marketing plan.

Comment: Why do uniforms matter here?

Comment: _Most uninformed people have no idea what it stands for_...wouldn't that be the definition of 'uninformed' in this situation?